# Issue with a css/html/js custom smoke animation not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Have been banging my head against the wall for a while now on this one and scoured our interwebs with no luck.

I have a person I'm building a site for who wants a custom smoke animation he purchased from a different web developer that was used on his other site to now be on his new site I'm working on.  That developer just sent me the whole ftp of the old site, with nothing on how the animation works.  I'm experienced in html and css, with a very little bit of jquery/js, but so far have not been able to get this to display properly in the new site.

Old site with proper smoke: http://www.rublaw.com

It appears to me that it uses some js scripts to call up the css effects, so I inserted the proper js using  tags at the end of the  in the html, made sure the .js file it calls up now sources to our ftp, made sure all the css was copied properly in my stylesheet, and inserted a  tag in the body with the same id to call up the process, but no luck.

New site where not working: http://www.oom.berlin

As you can see using Inspector on the new site, the animation is working in the background, it's just not visible.  I've tried playing with the display, z-index, and position properties of the CSS, tried inserting the "viewport" id which triggers the animation in different places in the html, but no luck.

Only one random thing, I found it showed up briefly when I inserted a default HTML audio player (wordpress default) into the page: once I remove the player, it disappeared again (we will not be using that in the site, there is a custom mp3 player there that we already have there).

I'm wondering if this has to do with Wordpress and/or the theme we're using (Artbees Jupiter) overriding it: the old site it was taken from was not wordpress.

Code:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-easing.min.js"></script>

<script type ="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 if(!$.browser.msie){
  var a=0;for(;a<15;a+=1){setTimeout(function b(){var a=Math.random()*1e3+8e3,c=$("<div />",{"class":"smoke",css:{opacity:0,left:Math.random()*100+80}});$(c).appendTo("#viewport");$.when($(c).animate({opacity:1},{duration:a/4,easing:"linear",queue:false,complete:function(){$(c).animate({opacity:0},{duration:a/3,easing:"linear",queue:false})}}),$(c).animate({bottom:$("#viewport").height()},{duration:a,easing:"linear",queue:false})).then(function(){$(c).remove();b()})},Math.random()*3e3)}
 }else{  
 "use strict";var a=0;for(;a<15;a+=1){setTimeout(function b(){var a=Math.random()*1e3+8e3,c=$("<div />",{"class":"smoke",css:{left:Math.random()*100+80}});$(c).appendTo("#viewport");$.when($(c).animate({},{duration:a/4,easing:"linear",queue:false,complete:function(){$(c).animate({},{duration:a/3,easing:"linear",queue:false})}}),$(c).animate({bottom:$("#viewport").height()},{duration:a,easing:"linear",queue:false})).then(function(){$(c).remove();b()})},Math.random()*3e3)}}}())
</script>
```

```css
.animated{animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-duration:1s; -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both; animation-timing-function:ease-in-out; -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}

.animated2{animation-duration:.5s;-webkit-animation-duration:.5s; -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both; animation-timing-function:ease-in-out; -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}

.animated3{animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-duration:1s; -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both; animation-timing-function:linear; -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear; animation-iteration-count:1; -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
}

.animated4{animation-duration:3s;-webkit-animation-duration:3s; -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both; animation-timing-function:ease-in-out; -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fade_eff{
0%{opacity:0; transform:translateY(-20px);-webkit-transform:translateY(-20px);}
100%{opacity:1; transform:translateY(0);-webkit-transform:translateY(0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade_eff{
0%{opacity:0; transform:translateY(-20px);-webkit-transform:translateY(-20px);}
100%{opacity:1; transform:translateY(0);-webkit-transform:translateY(0);}
}
.fade_eff{animation-name:fade_eff;-webkit-animation-name:fade_eff;}

@keyframes scale_eff{
0%{opacity:0; transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform:scale(0);}
100%{opacity:1; transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale_eff{
0%{opacity:0; transform:scale(0);-webkit-transform:scale(0);}
100%{opacity:1; transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
}
.scale_eff{animation-name:scale_eff;-webkit-animation-name:scale_eff;}

@keyframes drop_eff{
0%{transform:translateX(0);-webkit-transform:translateX(0);}
100%{transform:translateX(-82px);-webkit-transform:translateX(-82px);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes drop_eff{
0%{transform:translateX(0);-webkit-transform:translateX(0);}
100%{transform:translateX(-82px);-webkit-transform:translateX(-82px);}
}
.drop_eff{animation-name:drop_eff;-webkit-animation-name:drop_eff;-moz-animation-name:drop_eff;-o-animation-name:drop_eff;}


@keyframes drop_eff2{
0%{opacity:0;transform:translateY(100px);-webkit-transform:translateY(100px);}
100%{transform:translateY(0px);-webkit-transform:translateY(0px);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes drop_eff2{
0%{opacity:0;transform:translateY(100px);-webkit-transform:translateY(100px);}
100%{transform:translateY(0px);-webkit-transform:translateY(0px);}
}
.drop_eff2{animation-name:drop_eff2;-webkit-animation-name:drop_eff2;}

@keyframes drop_eff3{
0%{opacity:0;transform:translateY(-100px);-webkit-transform:translateY(-100px);}
100%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);-webkit-transform:translateY(0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes drop_eff3{
0%{opacity:0;transform:translateY(-100px);-webkit-transform:translateY(-100px);}
100%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);-webkit-transform:translateY(0);}
}

.drop_eff3{animation-name:drop_eff3;-webkit-animation-name:drop_eff3;-moz-animation-name:drop_eff3;-o-animation-name:drop_eff3;}

@keyframes drop_eff4{
0%{opacity:0;transform:translateX(-100px);-webkit-transform:translateX(-100px);}
100%{transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes drop_eff4{
0%{opacity:0;transform:translateX(-100px);-webkit-transform:translateX(-100px);}
100%{transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);}
}
.drop_eff4{animation-name:drop_eff4;-webkit-animation-name:drop_eff4;}

@-webkit-keyframes shake_eff {
0%, 100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(10deg); transform:rotate(10deg);}
10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg); transform:rotate(-10deg);}
20%, 40%, 60%, 80%{-webkit-transform:rotate(10deg); transform:rotate(10deg);}
}

@keyframes shake_eff {
0%, 100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(10deg); transform:rotate(10deg);}
10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg); transform:rotate(-10deg);}
20%, 40%, 60%, 80%{-webkit-transform:rotate(10deg); transform:rotate(10deg);}
}
.shake_eff{-webkit-animation-name: shake_eff;animation-name: shake_eff;}

@-webkit-keyframes shake_eff2 {
0%, 100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(10px); transform:rotate(10px);}
10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-10px); transform:translateX(-10px);}
20%, 40%, 60%, 80%{-webkit-transform:translateX(10px); transform:translateX(10px);}
}

@keyframes shake_eff2 {
0%, 100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(10px); transform:rotate(10px);}
10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-10px); transform:translateX(-10px);}
20%, 40%, 60%, 80%{-webkit-transform:translateX(10px); transform:translateX(10px);}
}
.shake_eff2{-webkit-animation-name: shake_eff2;animation-name: shake_eff2;}

#viewport{position:absolute; width:100%; overflow-x:hidden!important;}
#viewport .smoke{position:absolute;width:85%;height:100%; z-index:-1;
background:url('http://oom.berlin/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/smoke-texture2.png') no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%; bottom:0; left:0; opacity:0.5;}
```

```html
<div id="viewport></div>
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated: I'm not the strongest with js stuff so apologies if this is something that is right in front of my eyes.

Comment: You've got a js error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'browser' of undefined"

Comment: Caught that, and changed $ to jQuery in the code in order to make sure it doesn't come up as undefined in wordpress "noconflict" mode, but still no luck on getting the animation to show up.

Comment: You've got somme css not applyed on your new website. Check your class `.smoke`, on your new website, you don't have the rule.

Comment: I’ve checked meticulously through all the css files of the old website and the only instance of .smoke is the one at the bottom of the css code I just posted in my original post above, along with its parent #viewport element.  Those attributes show up if one inspects my new page as it does on the old one.

Comment: Have you changed something ? It works now. Before, you didn't have the `.smoke` in your new website, and your `div.smoke` had a 0px height